# How to extract a word(s) with digits from a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Sample text:

Calvin Klein K2R2S1K6 Women

I need to get the K2R2S1K6 of this example, it could be at any position in the string. Is it possible to get the first word with digits in it?

Comment: What if the brand name has a number in it? How do you define a word?

Comment: Thanks. The brand name never has a number in it. Even if it does it wouldn't be a problem, I can strip these before getting into this task.

Comment: or you can set a condition to select a word which has uppercase characters with number..

Comment: There is no built-in function for that. You can use a series of subqueries to get your value, but the easiest (and probably even fastest) way would be to write a stored function that goes through a string char by char and extract the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be something like:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('Calvin Klein K2R2S1K6 Women', '^(.*?)([^ ]*[0-9][^ ]*).*$', '\2')
```

I could only test it against PostgreSQL as I don't have MySQL at hand, so it may need minor tweaking. The regex is POSIX, though, so generally should work just like that.

Also, look here for some MySQL regex info:
[How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)